# Qt - Getting cleaner storage volumes info on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, storage

I am using `QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()` to get a volume list, and then `rootPath()` for each one, but I am getting messy results:

```
/storage/613C-16DF Y
/storage/emulated N 
/storage YN
/persist N
/efs N
/firmware-modem N
/firmware N
/cache N
/data N
/system Y
N
N
N
N
N
N
/mnt YN
```

`Y` means it works as expected, `N` means it doesn't work at all, `YN` - some subdirs work, others don't. There are also 6 "nameless" volumes, none of which work.

There is also `/storage/emulated/0` which is not listed, but I know for a fact that it works and gives me the integrated storage.

From a regular user's perspective, the device should list only two volumes:

```
/storage/emulated/0 - integrated memory
/storage/613C-16DF - external sd card
```

It is also strange that I can get from `/storage` to `/613C-16DF`, but I can't go to `/emulated` even tho I can go directly to `/storage/emulated/0`.

The question is how to get cleaner results. I could hard-code `/storage/emulated/0`, but I cannot hard-code the external sd card volume as it varies, plus there is the possibility the device has more user volumes.

Filtering out all the ones that are not `isValid()` gets rid of the blank ones, but the rest is the same.

It may be relevant that I am using the (experimental?) QML `Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1` API.

Comment: dtech, confused: `QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()` is a qt class? while search for  `Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1` does not include a type `mountedVolumes`?

Comment: `QStorageInfo` is a C++ class, unrelated to `folderlistmodel`.

Comment: but your last line means what ?

Comment: It means that on the GUI side I am using QML with `folderlistmodel` rather than the QtWidget based file models/dialogs.

Comment: I think you can get internal storage location (/storage/emulated/0) with `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation)`. AFAIK you can't get external sd card locations through `QStandardPaths`.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` is the only one I don't have a problem with, it is a given.

Answer (score 0):

OK, some basic regexing appears to do the trick to isolate usable removable volumes:

- `/\/storage\/[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}/` for SD cards
- `/\/mnt\/media_rw\/[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}/` for USB drives

So in C++ we get the system volumes as a JS array of objects:

```
QVariantList volumes() {
  QVariantList l;
  for (const auto & i : QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()) {
    QVariantMap m;
    m.insert("name", i.name());
    m.insert("dname", i.displayName());
    m.insert("valid", i.isValid());
    m.insert("readonly", i.isReadOnly());
    m.insert("ready", i.isReady());
    m.insert("rootPath", i.rootPath());
    m.insert("bsize", i.blockSize());
    m.insert("available", i.bytesAvailable() / (1024 * 1024));
    m.insert("free", i.bytesFree() / (1024 * 1024));
    m.insert("total", i.bytesTotal() / (1024 * 1024));
    l.append(m);
  }
  return l;
}
```

And in QML we do a little "model filtering" in case of android:

```
  function getVolumes() {
    var v = SY.volumes()
    switch (Qt.platform.os) {
    case "android":
      var l = []
      var sd = /\/storage\/[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}/, sdc = 1
      var usb = /\/mnt\/media_rw\/[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}/, usbc = 1
      l.push({"name" : "Internal Storage", "rootPath": "/storage/emulated/0", "valid" : true})
      for (var c = 0; c < v.length; ++c) { // for-in doesn't work?!?
        if (sd.test(v[c].rootPath)) {
          v[c].name = "SD Card " + sdc++ // name is blank on android
          l.push(v[c])
        } else if (usb.test(v[c].rootPath)) {
          v[c].name = "USB drive " + usbc++
          l.push(v[c])
        }
      }
      return l
    default: return v
    }
  }
```

Note that I haven't tested the USB part due to current lack of a working M micro usb to F usb adapter, it is based on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140282/154380). Also note that `/storage/emulated/0` doesn't implement all the extra properties, in my case they weren't necessary, if they are they should be populated explicitly.